# Kitten's voice & growth rate

Tags: cats, vocalizations, junior-pets, growing

I have a kitten who meows silently, but purrs perfectly well. She is also growing at a slower rate than other kittens born around the same time. She seems perfectly healthy & quite frankly very animated. She is approximately 4 months old, but has the size of a 2 month old kitten. Is there dwarfism in cats? Her mother does the same thing, is it hereditary?

This is my 1st question to this site. Please forgive me if I did something wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site Pets.

Comment: Welcome to Pets. Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. Silent meowing is actually quite common, especially in kittens. The loudness of a cats voice seems to be a personality trait and can change during life (usually becomming louder once they figure out that humans react to it)

Comment: It's also possible the cat is meowing at a frequency higher than humans can hear. Cats are known to do that sometimes. You might hear the cat exhale when meowing, but otherwise make no audible noise in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could add a question :) What do you want to know? If you should be concerned? How you could help the cat? If the kitten likes to learn dancing? ;) you got the point

Comment: Hi wellcome to pets,can you post a picture of your cat,it will be helpful when answering this question.

Comment: Hi again Lisa, addressing your most recently edited-in question: yes, dwarfism occurs in cats and is hereditary and source for more information is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_cat